# when does admin.autodiscover() get executed (python newbie)

Tags: python, django, django-views

i don't seem to understand when does such statement get executed ? 
I mean by such statement those which are 0 indented in a .py file (same indent as the from statement)

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are executed when the module is imported.

```
# test.py
print("Here!")

def foo():
    print("There!")
```

```
# main.py
print("A")
import test
print("B")
test.foo()
print("C")
```

```
$ python main.py
A
Here!
B
There!
C
```